# C# Background Worker divison

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, backgroundworker

I am trying to use a background worker which for each key in a dictionary save the contents to file. *ACon is a personal class that calls a save function on the contents of a dictionary within it.*

```
   private void bwSaver_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] Keys = ACon.GetKeys();
        int num = 0;

        foreach (string s in Keys)
        {
            ACon.Save(s);
            int Len = Keys.Length;
            double pctg = (num / Len);

            //Below was by first attempt at getting the percentage. Above are my debugging attempts.
            bwSaver.ReportProgress(num/Keys.Length*100);
            num++;
        }
    }
```

I was hoping for it to report the progress by giving the key it is on / total keys * 100 for percentage but this wasn't working.

No matter what type I use for pctg; short, int, float, double,  **num/Len** always = 0, yet if I switch it around, **Len/num** gives the correct value. Adding or removing brackets doesn't change anything. Am I just being silly and missing something or am I coding something wrong?

Here is some screenshots from VS2010 (Professional)

*pctg as double:*
[image: pctg as double]

*pctg as float:*
[image: pctg as float]

*pctg as double, without brackets:*
[image: pctg as double, without brackets]

*pctg with Len and num swapped:*
[image: pctg with Len and num swapped]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not that you are changing the type for pctg, its based on the types of num and Len

Try:

```
float pctg = ((float)num / (float)Len);
```

If both `num` and `Len` are ints, then your code would do integer division, after which it would cast that integer to a float.

As mentioned by @CDspace below, the integer division will round to the nearest int, in your case, zero.  Then casting zero to any other type is still zero.

Comment: This works, but if this is the case, how come switching Len/num gives a result, without casting?

Comment: Does len/num give a whole integer value?  Without the cast you are doing integer division (if len and num are ints), so you round to the nearest int.

Comment: Note, `Len/num` gives you a value because `Len > num`, it's probably still losing it's fractional part because of the integer devision

Comment: Yeah, changing the values to give something like 4/3, gives 1.

Comment: @Ewan, CDspace is correct.  I was trying say that with "integer division" but he is more succinct. :)